# How do access both list and model using @ MVC

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core, model

I know .NetCore MVC does not allow two models in one view like `@model IEnumerable<Fundi.HR.Web.Models.Employee>` and `@model Employees` but what do I do if I want to access both the list variables within my model   `@foreach (var item in Model)` and when creating new object, **just a side note these are all in one view I created a popup, to add new employees**

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why not create a view model to hold both of the props? Then use that view model in the view as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create one view model for both

```
public EmployeeViewModel
{
 public List<Fundi.HR.Web.Models.Employee> Employees {get; set;}
 public Employee Employee {get; set;}
}
```

you can use it this way

```
@model EmployeeViewModel
.....
  @foreach (var item in Model.Employees)
{
.....
}
```

and action

```
.....
  var model= new EmployeeViewModel();
  model.Employee= context.Employeees..... .FirstOrDefault() // replace with your code
 model.Employees= context.Employeees.ToList() // replace with your code
  return View(model);
```

Comment: **Hi, I used what you suggested but i got this error how can I fix this **  InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Fundi.HR.Web.Models.Employee]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Fundi.HR.Web.Models.EmployeeViewModel'.

Comment: @Mbali I added some code. Pls check my answer